# Facebook JS SDK vs other modules: Alternatively, why there is Java code difference?

Tags: javascript, facebook, module, difference

**Javascript difference:** It's basic but most may not know it. I'm trying to called function using onclick event but it works differently on facebook. Look at the two examples.

**In usual syntax used in websites;**

```
    <button id="btn" onclick="getscore()">Test</button>
    <script>
    var score = 1;
    function getscore(){
    ++score;
    scorep.innerHTML = score;
    }
    </script>
```

**Facebook syntax;**

```
    <button id="btn">Test</button>
    <script>
    var score = 1;
    btn.onclick = function(){
    ++score;
    scorep.innerHTML = score;
    }
    </script>
```

So the code in fb test console won't work in my site page & vice verca.

1. Why is there a difference?
2. How do I resolve this?

Thanking in advance to my rescuers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Should work

```
<button id="btn">Test</button>
<script>
var score = 1;
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
++score;
scorep.innerHTML = score;
}
</script>
```